# Django: Unsupported media type

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send image from react to django rest framework,this is what I tried so far,it gives Unsupported media type error, I am not sure if the  problem is in the backend or frontend part. What else should I do in order to make it work?

> backend

views.py

```
class ImageView(APIView):
    permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes=[MultiPartParser,FormParser]

    def post(self,request,format=None):
        print(request.data)
        serializer=ImageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save();
            return Response(status=200)
```

serializer.py

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)  :
    class Meta:
        model=Images;
        fields=['image']
```

models.py

```
def upload_to(instance,filename):
    return 'images/{filename}'.format(filename=filename)

class Images(models.Model):
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT=BASE_DIR.joinpath('media')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

> frontend

Send_file.js

```
const Send_file=()=>{
    const send_data=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
      
        let data={
            'image':e.target[0].files[0]
        }
        axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/upload_image/`,data,config)

    }
    return <>
    <form  enctype='multipart/form-data' onSubmit = {send_data}>
        <input  type='file'/>
        <button type='submit'>SEND FILE</button>
    </form>
    </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `FileField` in the ImageSerializer.

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    upload_image = serializers.FileField(max_length = 10000000, allow_empty_file = False, use_url = False, write_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('upload_image', 'image')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        image_source = validated_data.pop('upload_image')
        new_image = Images.objects.create(image = image_source)
        return new_image
```

And please change the `image` key in the data object in Send_file.js into `upload_image`.

```
const Send_file=()=>{
    const send_data=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
      
        let data={
            'upload_image':e.target[0].files[0]                 # here 
        }
        axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/upload_image/`,data,config)

    }
    ...
}
```